# hyperledger blockchain-explorer failed to connect client peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

First, my environment has peer0 and peer1, and this is my first-network.json file

```
{
    "name": "first-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "client": {
        "tlsEnable": true,
        "adminUser": "admin",
        "adminPassword": "adminpw",
        "enableAuthentication": false,
        "organization": "org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "base-chain": {
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.arxanfintech.com": {}
            },
            "connection": {
                "timeout": {
                    "peer": {
                        "endorser": "6000",
                        "eventHub": "6000",
                        "eventReg": "6000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "fullpath": false,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.arxanfintech.com/users/Admin@org1.arxanfintech.com/msp/keystore/4cd98e6f90b39e102c060c86b6bcd13311c1fd005dd2fc8571f9b725ce25512d_sk"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.arxanfintech.com/users/Admin@org1.arxanfintech.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.arxanfintech.com-cert.pem"
            }
        },
        "orderer": {
            "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/arxanfintech.com/users/Admin@arxanfintech.com/msp/keystore/88b5b11eff55eb580d71dfbfd81d6ff2b11f83e3e5fad98f267c22db332ec359_sk"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/arxanfintech.com/users/Admin@arxanfintech.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@arxanfintech.com-cert.pem"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.arxanfintech.com": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.arxanfintech.com/peers/peer0.org1.arxanfintech.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs//:192.168.20.77:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.arxanfintech.com"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.arxanfintech.com": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.arxanfintech.com/peers/peer1.org1.arxanfintech.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs//:192.168.20.77:8051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.arxanfintech.com"
            }
        },
        "orderers": {
            "orderer0.arxanfintech.com": {
                "tlsCACerts": {
                    "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/arxanfintech.com/orderers/orderer0.arxanfintech.com/tls/ca.crt"
                },
                "url": "grpcs//:192.168.20.77:7050",
                "grpcOptions": {
                    "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer0.arxanfintech.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: who can help me,is emergency

Comment: Hi Shen, I don't know the technology but I suggest you to clarify your question. It's too generic. Provide the steps you executed and the error you receive.

Comment: I suggest you to see the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. For example, add the error in your question and explain what you have done so people can reproduce it and help you.

Comment: error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
ssl_transport_security.cc:636] Could not load any root certificate

Comment: thank you , i think i should see the guidelines

Comment: when i tried to do ./start.sh,this is the error

Comment: I edited your question with the information you provided. The more specific you are in your question, the more people who knows the technology can helps you :) Remember that-'s better to update your question, not add many comments.